# Make Resize() more specific?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a range that gets resizes and I am wanting to know if there is a way to make the resizing more specific. ie `.Resize(,7)` Would be B-G columns But I'm wanting only B,F,G columns.

This is the line I'm working with.

```
   a = .Range("b2", .Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 7).Value
```

---

```
Private Sub TextBox_Search_Change()
    Select Case True
        Case OptionButton_User_Name.Value
            Dim a, i As Long, ii As Long, n As Long, temp As String
            If Len(Me.TextBox_Search.Value) Then
                temp = UCase(Me.TextBox_Search.Value)
                With Sheets("ToolData")
                    a = Union(.Range("B:B"), .Range("F:F"), .Range("G:G")).Value
                End With
                a = Application.Transpose(a)
                For i = 1 To UBound(a, 2)
                    If UCase(a(1, i)) Like "*" & temp & "*" Or _
                    UCase(a(2, i)) Like "*" & temp & "*" Then
                        n = n + 1
                        For ii = 1 To UBound(a, 1)
                            a(ii, n) = a(ii, i)
                        Next
                    End If
                Next
                If n > 0 Then
                    ReDim Preserve a(1 To UBound(a, 1), 1 To n)
                    Me.ListBox_History.Column = a
                End If
            Else
                With Sheets("ToolData")
                    Me.ListBox_History.List = .Range("b2", .Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 7).Value
                End With
            End If
            Case Else
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Union` might be a good place to start. In a simple example, it could work for you like this:

```
Dim r as Range
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set r = Union(.Range("B:B"),.Range("F:F"),.Range("G:G"))
End With
```

Comment: God, I love you guys. Always learning new ways of doing things from you all. I'm going to fit what you gave me to my needs and let you know how it turns out.

Comment: Okay your solution can and will work but I'm causing an  "type mismatch" error when I implement it.

Comment: @WilliamSmith  Just update your question with the code you have if you really can't get it working. One thing I'd say is note that my variable `r` is a range and your variable `a` isn't - that might be causing problems. You could dim r as variant and add `.Value` after the `Union`

Comment: Yes 'Dim a As Long'

Comment: The problem I have is with `a = Application.Transpose(a)` edit first question with whole code

Comment: @WilliamSmith use a `Range` variable like I have, say `r`, and try `a = Application.Transpose(r)`.

Comment: If you can't get that part to work I'd suggest asking in a new question as it is different to the question here :) would be more that happy to help further there